# How to add conditional !important in stylus

Tags: stylus

I want to add a conditional `!important` string to a definition *without having to duplicate the lines*... The closest I've come so far is this:

```
fontSize(size, isImportant = false)
  importantString=""
  if isImportant
    importantString = !important

  font-size unit(size, 'px') importantString
  font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem') importantString
```

which doesn't work because `importantString=""` actually inserts `""`, and removing the assignment actually prints `importantString` if it isn't defined.

The best way would be something like:

```
font-size unit(size, 'px') if isImportant !important
```

But I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering your question — you can just use `unquote()` around the quotes for `importantString`, so it would output to nothing if there is no `important`.

That would look like this:

```
fontSize(size, isImportant = false)
  importantString = isImportant ? !important : unquote("")

  font-size unit(size, 'px') importantString
  font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem') importantString
```

However! if you'd ask me, I'd recommend to make *something different* — make a transparent mixin for `font-size` like this:

```
font-size(size, args...)
  $rem_ratio = 10 if not $rem_ratio is defined
  if unit(size) == 'rem'
    font-size unit(size * $rem_ratio, 'px') args
    font-size size args
  else if unit(size) == ''
    font-size unit(size, 'px') args
    font-size unit(size / $rem_ratio, 'rem') args
  else
    font-size arguments
```

That mixin could be used transparently as you could use the generic `font-size`. Even more, there are two ways to use it:

```
.foo
  font-size 1rem

.bar
  font-size 10
```

You can use `rem` unit there, that would be translated to pixels in a fallback, or use unitless number, that would be translated as you wanted it to be in your question. And the importance would be preserved and you'd even have a way to declare how much pixels are there in one `rem` using `$rem_ratio` variable.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

There might be a cleaner solution, but I would opt for something like:

```
fontSize(size, isImportant = false)
  if isImportant
    font-size unit(size, 'px') !important
    font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem') !important
  else
    font-size unit(size, 'px')
    font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem')
```

**Update:** Alternate solution, using rest parameters:

```
fontSize(size, args...)
  font-size unit(size, 'px') args
  font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem') args
```

Usage:

```
p
  fontSize(12, !important)

h1
  fontSize(14)
```

**Update:** Named argument, perhaps nicer:

```
fontSize(size, important = null)
  font-size unit(size, 'px') important
  font-size unit(size / 10, 'rem') important
```

Comment: I had this solution implemented and wanted a cleaner one. I'll specify it in the question. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

In "display" no compile

Stylus

```
display block !important
```

Css

```
display:block
```

Answer (score 0):

```
display( arg = '' )
    if arg == 'inline-block'
        display arg
        zoom 1
        *display inline
    else if arg == 'box'
        display -moz-box
        display -webkit-box
        display box
    else
        display arg
```

Comment: REVIEW: Some description for your solution would be appreciated.